# Converting DER Encoded Key to PEM Format in Java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pem, asn.1, der

I am writing Java code to create a pair of RSA keys using the class *KeyPairGenerator* (which as I understand are created in DER format). I am then wanting to utilize some of the key's bytes in another separate calculation. Therefore, I presume I need to convert it into PEM format using something like *BouncyCastle*. However if I compare the converted bytes from the PEM file to a PEM file created using *openssl* from the same source DER file, the bytes differ.

Can someone please help explain why?

regards,
Geof.

Comment: PEM is a Base64-encoded representation of DER-encoded message. Where do you get different bytes?

Comment: Bouncycastle: MIICXAIBAAKBgQCQl4 ....  
openssl: MIICdgIBADANBgkqhkiG9 ....  

  The former I'm using PEMWriter to create a PEM file from the DER encoding. The latter I am executing the command: openssl pkcs8 -nocrypt -inform DER -in private.der -out private.pem (sorry for the formatting, docs say 2 spaces for newline, 4 spaces to indent, but I can't get it to do that)

Comment: A Java `KeyPair` object, and its privateKey and PublicKey portions, are "created" in a Java internal representation. The `.getEncoded()` method on either half *returns* a DER encoding of "PKCS#8" format for privatekey or "X.509" (more exactly SubjectPublicKeyInfo) for publickey; see javadoc for `java.security.Key`. Also those "excerpts" are identical. OpenSSL does support three different file formats for RSA private keys; are the types in the BEGIN lines "PRIVATE KEY" vs "RSA PRIVATE KEY"? If so those are just different formats. @CryptoGuy PEM is base64 of DER *plus BEGIN and END lines*.

Comment: Bouncycastle begins with: "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----". openssl begins with: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----". Sorry you said "Also, those excerpts are identical" - I don't understand why you say that as the bytes appear to be completely different - are you saying they're actually the same but just encoded differently? thanks.